# Correct PHP syntax and variable interpolation mail()

Tags: php, string, variables

I have this code to send out an email:

```
// create email body and send it - for a domain price offer 
$to = 'user@domain.com';
$email_subject = "$$price offer for $domain";
$email_body =   " $name is offering $$price for $domain \n\n ".
        " Message: $message \n\n ".
        " Contact: $email_address ";

$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
//$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Domain Parking <domainforsale@domain.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: ' . $email_address . "\r\n";
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
```

Note the `$email_subject` and `$email_body` variables; I'm using `$$price` to output something like `$12.34`.

Is that a good idea? Are there better ways to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: Variable interpolation in double quoted strings has no relation to short tags.

Comment: What is the question?  Please ask a specific question.  For example: "Will this code work if ..."

Comment: Thanks! How about the $$price ? Should be \$$price and is this whole code correct at all?

Comment: @Yatko I see what you are asking now.  The readable option is to not put your variables in the string at all.  Otherwise, your code is difficult to scan and read.

Comment: Thank you @Brad, I changed the code based on your and Thom Wiggers suggestion. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
$foo = "bar"; 
echo "$$foo"; //prints $bar
```

So that's that. Using this syntax would be a lot more readable though:

```
echo '$' . $foo;
```

Other than that you should read the http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php page. It, amoung other things, specifies that you should use `\r\n` to separate headers, whilst you are using `\n\n` in a few places.

Answer (score 1):

Although it works, it would be recommended to do one of the following instead:

```
$email_subject = '$' . $price . ' offer for ' . $domain;

$email_subject = sprintf('$%s price offer for %s', $price, $domain);

$email_subject = "\$$price offer for $domain";
```

Btw, `mail()` will probably do this for you, but you should sanitize the variables to make sure they don't contain a newline character.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to do format things using [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprintf) like this:

```
// create email body and send it - for a domain price offer 
$to = 'user@domain.com';
$email_subject = sprintf("%s offer for %s", $price, $domain);
$email_body = sprintf("%s is offering %s for $domain \n\n ", $name, $price)
            . sprintf(" Message: %s \n\n ", $message)
            . sprintf(" Contact: %s ", $email_address)
            ;

$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
//$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Domain Parking <domainforsale@domain.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: ' . $email_address . "\r\n";
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
```